# Is there a way to Track/trace and log all the methods, by Class and Method name, during a debug session?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, trace

I am not interested in logging into frameworks or under the covers but only at my source level code upon entry and exit of each method. I would like it to provide Class Name and Method Name and log it to file or at least have it fly by on the screen.

My query is if it is possible with existing Xcode/Debugger/Instruments facilities, can I implement it in an easy way other than an NSLog statement at every method entry and exit, or is there a commercial tool that provides this capability ?

I'm talking source methods here... not execution processes or threads. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using Instruments, like the Time Profiler instrument, for this?

Comment: Well... because it does not track, trace or log my source code methods, which is what I was asking about in my question.

Comment: It certainly lets you see what methods were executed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dave Dribin covers precisely this in his article [Tracing Objective-C messages](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/).

The part you are after is probably this:

> If you set the `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` environment variable to `YES`, the Objective-C runtime will log all dispatched Objective-C messages to a file named /tmp/msgSends-<pid>.

Comment: this sounds really on the mark. I tried setting the environment for debugging in Xcode 4.1 but I don't see the file named /tmp/msgSends-<pid> anyplace. Actually, I can't find a /tmp folder. Do you have a hint as to where it s hanging off of ? Thx.

Comment: I'm there. I had not realized that the tmp folder was hidden and I needed to get to it via Terminal. Many thanks.

Comment: Obviously this won't work on iOS. The function in the Obj-C runtime is stubbed out.

Answer (score 2):

Xtrace (https://github.com/johnno1962/Xtrace) has many features and works well for tracing Objective-C. One needs source access to their project, like you appear to have, and can emit messages on entry/exit, like you appear to want.

- Debug-time configuration - can hard-code or configure tracing while debugging
- Uncomplicated integration - one .mm and one .h
- NSRegularExpression matching - classes, methods, types

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which you can use with `iOS simulator` on the Mac (arm/x86_64)

1. Create a `Symbolic Breakpoint`
2. Symbol: `objc_msgSend`
3. Action: `Debugger Command`
4. Command:

   ```
   p (void)printf("[%s, %s]\n", (char*)object_getClassName($arg1), $arg2)
   ```

   *`p` is an alias for `expr --`
5. Check: `Automatically continue after evaluating actions`

[image]